# Evans Problem 5.15 - Proof Verification

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

The following question is an exercise from Evans' textbook *Partial Differential Equations*.

Given $\alpha > 0$ and $U = B_0(0,1)$, show that there exists a constant $C$, depending only on $n$ and $\alpha$, such that
$$\int_U u^2 dx \leq C \int_U |\nabla u|^2 dx$$
provided $|\{x\in U | u(x) = 0\}| \equiv |M| \geq \alpha > 0$ and $u\in H^1(U)$.

This question has been asked before on this website. However, I am writing to verify my proposed solution. Here it is:

**Proof:**

Define $\alpha' = |\{x\in U | u(x) = 0\}| \equiv |M|$.  By assumption, $\alpha' \geq \alpha > 0$. Let $u \in H^1(U)$. If $\alpha' = |U|$, then $|M^c| = 0$. Hence $u$ is non-zero on a set of measure zero. The inequality is true trivially. So WLOG assume that $\alpha' \neq |U|$. Since $U$ is an open, connected set with $C^1$ boundary, Poincare's inequality implies that:

$$
||u - u_U ||_{L^2(U)}
\leq 
C
|| Du ||_{L^2(U)}.
$$

for some constant $C > 0$. We directly manipulate the inequality above.  First note that:

$$
    C
    || Du ||_{L^2(U)}
    \geq 
    || u - u_U ||_{L^2(U)}
    \geq 
    || u  ||_{L^2(U)}
    -
    || u_U ||_{L^2(U)}
    =
    || u  ||_{L^2(U)}
    -
    | u_U | |U|^{1/2}
    \geq 
    ||u||_{L^2(U)}
    -
    \frac{1}{|U|^{1/2}}
    \int_{U} |u(x)| dx.
$$

The first inequality follows from Poincare's inequality.
The second inequality follows from the triangle inequality.
The third equality follows by the definition of the $L^2$ norm.
The fourth inequality is a simple estimate using the definition of $u_U$.
Continuing with the manipulations, we have:

$$
    ||u||_{L^2(U)}
    -
    \frac{1}{|U|^{1/2}}
    \int_{U} |u(x)| dx
    =
    || u  ||_{L^2(U)}
    - 
    \frac{1}{|U|^{1/2}}
    \int_{M^c}
    |u(x)| dx
    \geq 
    || u  ||_{L^2(U)}
    -
    \frac{|M^c|^{1/2}}{|U|^{1/2}}
    ||u||_{L^2(U)}.
$$

The first equality follows since $u \equiv 0$ on $M$.
The second inequality follows from Holder's inequality and noting that $||u||_{L^2(U)} \geq ||u||_{L^2(M^c)}$.
Noting that:

$$
|| u  ||_{L^2(U)}
    -
\bigg ( \frac{|M^c|}{|U|} \bigg )^{1/2}
||u||_{L^2(U)}
=
|| u  ||_{L^2(U)}
    -
\bigg ( \frac{|U| - |M| }{|U|} \bigg )^{1/2}
||u||_{L^2(U)}
=
\bigg (
1
-
\sqrt{ 1 - \frac{|M| }{|U|} }
\bigg )
||u||_{L^2(U)}
$$

All in all, we have:

$$
||u||_{L^2(U)}
\leq 
\frac{C }{ \bigg (
1
-
\sqrt{ 1 - \frac{|M| }{|U|} }
\bigg )  } ||Du||_{L^2(U)}
$$

Taking squares on both sides since both sides are non-negative yields the desired result.

Please feel free to critique the proof.

Comment: Nice proof :) I can't see any issues with it except that, right at the end, you should use that $\vert M \vert \geqslant \alpha$ since $M$ depends on $u$, so at the moment your "constant" isn't really a constant

Comment: Ahh, yes. Thanks!